# форма срабатывает при добавлении изображении, а не при нажатии кнопки

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. Проблема такая: нашел плагин http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#extrahtml, всё сделал под себя, но в самом конце понять не могу, почему форма отправляется на сервер только при добавлении изображения, а не при нажатии кнопки, то есть вот код:

```
  <button type="button" id="extrabutton" value="1" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-success"><font><font>Начать загрузку</font></font></button>
```

Тут я задаю `value` `1`, чтобы проверить на сервере, а далее ajax запрос

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var extraObj = $("#singleupload").uploadFile({
      url: "upload.php",
      fileName: "myfile",
      acceptFiles: "image/*",
      allowedTypes: "jpg,jpeg,png,gif",
      showPreview: true,
      multiple: false,
      previewHeight: "100px",
      maxFileCount: 1,
      previewWidth: "auto",
      showDelete: true,
      showFileCounter: false,
      returnType: "html",
      maxFileCountErrorStr: "Вы не можете загружать более одного изображения",
      statusBarWidth: 600,
      autoSubmit: false,
      dragdropWidth: 600,
      dragDropStr: "Перетащите файл или откройте ",
      abortStr: "Не загруженно",
      cancelStr: "Отмена",
      uploadStr: "Открыть",
      dynamicFormData: function() {
        var data = {
            login: $("#login").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
            lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
            position: $("#position").val(),
            specialization: $("#specialization").val(),
            number_Phone: $("#number_Phone").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            education: $("#education").val(),
            attainment: $("#attainment").val(),
            about: $("#about").val(),
            extrabutton: $("#extrabutton").val()
          } //подготовил для передачи на сервер значение с кнопкой
        return data;
      },
      onSuccess: function(files, data, xhr, pd) {
        $("#eventsmessage").html($("#eventsmessage").html() + "Success for: " + JSON.parse(data));
      },
      onError: function(files, status, errMsg, pd) {
        alert("error");
        $("#display_messaggi").html(errMsg);
      },
      onSubmit: function(files) {
        //files : List of files to be uploaded
        //return flase;   to stop upload
      }
    });
    $("#extrabutton").click(function() {

      extraObj.startUpload();

    });
  });
</script>
```

Тут встречаю, т.е. даю условие, что код обрабатывать, когда нажата кнопка `extrabutton`

```
if(isset($_POST["extrabutton"]))
{
```

Но пока кнопка не работает, то есть форма отправляется по схеме загрузи картинку нажми кнопку, помогите всем спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Замените

```
if(isset($_POST["extrabutton"]))
```

на

```
if (isset($_POST["extrabutton"]) && !empty($_POST["extrabutton"]))
```

или

```
if (isset($_POST["extrabutton"]) == "1")
```

Comment: не помогло суть в том, что все равно требует новое изоражение